# Error in adding custom table in user identity system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, code-first

I was following this article to add my custom table.
http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customizing-users-profile-to-add-new.html
**In My AccountViewModels.cs, i have tried to add new custom table(UserProfileInfo) something like this---**

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfileInfo UserProfileInfo { get; set; }
}
public class UserProfileInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string MobileNum { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UserProfileInfo> UserProfileInfo { get; set; }

}
```

}

and in my Account Controller's Register action (Post Version), i have tried to update register action like this but you can see in code at city and mobileNum,
its stating ----- 
**xxx.RegisterViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'City' and no extension method 'City' accepting a first argument of type 'xxx.RegisterViewModel' could be found....**

```
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, EmailID = model.EmailID,
                UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo 
                { City = model.City,
                  MobileNum = model.ModileNum
                }
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

i dont know what's happening here.plzz help me out.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that article as u mentioned.You will never be able to pass City and mobile number as parameter as u have not defined them in register view model.

If u simply want to just create and another table and wants to save that into database then u can do it like this-------

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            user.HomeTown = model.HomeTown;
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and change your Dbcontext to something like this----

```
         public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserProfileInfo> UserProfileInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

and your Application user class should be something like this-----

```
      public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
    public string HomeTown { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfileInfo UserProfileInfo { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: thnxx for ur solution.I was also wondering why my code was not working

Answer (score 0):

You've created separated table - UserProfileInfo - that isn't part of ApplicationUser one.
What you've to do is:

1. crate new ApplicationUser
2. create new UserProfileInfo
3. link each other with proper navigation property or assign foreign keys manually (depending on your configuration)

Comment: thnks ..I have mentioned at the top that which article i was following. In that article , nothing is mentioned on to create a new ApplicationUser.

Comment: you are doing it just after checking if model is valid: var user = new ApplicationUser()

Comment: so, should i not check model state before posting it. then, what about the validation and other attributes then they will not work as expected

Comment: The problem is in line where you are creating ApplicationUser, not with the  validation. Replace your code with something like that: var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, EmailID = model.EmailID };
UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo { City = model.City, MobileNum = model.ModileNum }; and it will start to work. Just remember about linking your ApplicationUser to UserProfileInfo (with foreign key - if it's needed)